# inotifywait exclude file types

Tags: shell-script, inotify

I'm using inotifywait in a script and wondering if there is a way to exclude hidden files from being watched?

I can't seem to determine the regex pattern to exclude hidden files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean filenames that start with a dot (`.`), you can ignore those. The thing with `inotifywait --exclude` is that the pattern appears to be matched against the full path of the file, so you'll need to take that into account.

So, if you give `inotifywait` the directories `foo` and `bar` to watch, then the patterns match against filenames like `foo/something`, `bar/somethingelse`. As usual in regexes, you need to escape the dot.

This should watch for all creates in the current directory except for dotfiles (it's a regex, so we need to escape the dots):

```
inotifywait -ecreate -m --exclude '^\./\.' .
```

Or, less specifically, exclude dotfiles in any directories, by looking for the combination of a slash and dot:

```
inotifywait -ecreate -m --exclude '/\.' foo bar
```

That, of course, will not work if you're watching a directory with a leading dot in some part of the path; it'll match everything in that path.